# What is the standard notation to represent the set of primes?

Tags: notation, prime-numbers

I have seen $\mathbb Z_p$. Are there others, perhaps $\mathbb N_p$?

or the set of natural numbers where the totient of $ n $ equal $ n - 1 $ ?
$$ \{n \in \mathbb N \mid n\ge2,\phi (n) = n-1\}$$

Comment: I have seen $\mathbb N_p$

Comment: Do you *need* a notation?

Comment: Well, "Let $p\in\{n\in\mathbb N\mid \phi(n)=n-1\}$" is only applicable, if you really want to to confuse the reader. But then, I would prefer: "Let $n$ be an integer, such that $n\mid (n-1)!+1$".

Comment: @Tomas: that makes $1$ prime, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: Oops, then it's an obfuscation of "Let $n\in\mathbb P\cup\{1\}$". :P

Comment: Yes, the obfuscation of a prime should exclude 1. Edited.

Comment: $\mathbb{P} = \{ n \in \mathbb{N}: n\geq 2 \;\text{ and }\; (\forall p \in \mathbb{N}, \; \; p|n \implies p = 1 \;\text{ or }\; p = n)\}$

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ does not refer to the set of primes.  Depending on the context, it either refers to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ or the $p$-adic integers.

The most common notation that I have seen for the set of primes is $\mathbb{P}$; however, it is not universally used, and so you should make sure to define it whenever you use it.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}$ is usually projective space, as in $\mathbb{RP}^n$ or $\mathbb{CP}^n$

Answer (score 13):

$\mathbb{P}$ seems to be fairly common.

Answer (score 12):

It is surprisingly common to eschew any such notation and, instead, rely on a convention that $p$ (and $p'$, $p_n$ etc) always denotes a prime number.

In fact, you can see that convention used in a [recent question right here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456368/attempted-exercise-using-littlewoods-theorem).

Answer (score 11):

I have seen $ \mathbb N_p $ and also  $ \mathbb P$.

Comment: Is this the case where P = NP?

Answer (score 4):

IF we use  $\mathbb P$, we have to clarify that it shall be the set of Primes like this:
$\mathbb P = \{ p \in \mathbb N \; | \; \text{p is prime}\}$.
As far as I know there is no official definition for the set of primes.
Mostly seen in my literature is e.g. *Let a $\in \mathbb C$, let p be prime*.

Source: I'm studying math @ Free University of Berlin.

Comment: What does "official" mean here?

Comment: We learned, that the natural numbers are defined as $\mathbb N = ...$ so I'd consider this a "official" definition, since somehow most mathematicians agreed to this.